# Update an existing Azure load balancer with a new rule fails

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to update an existing Loadbalancer with new Rule.

I am executing the following command as per the documentation from microsoft. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-arm-ps#update-an-existing-load-balancer

```
$slb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name  LB-Some-primary -ResourceGroupName SomeName
$slb | Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name "Test" -FrontendIpConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -FrontendPort 29700 -BackendPort 24700 -Protocol TCP
$slb | Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer
```

I get the following error

```
Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer : Adding or updating NAT Rules when NAT pool is present on loadbalancer /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/LB-xxxx-primary is not supported. To modify the load balancer, pass 
in all NAT rules unchanged or remove the LoadBalancerInboundNatRules property from your PUT request.
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : 'xxxx-2596-4c9e-a30a-12be70fxxxxx'
At line:1 char:8
+ $slb | Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer], NetworkCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.SetAzureLoadBalancerCommand
```

I get the same error from Azure CLI as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems like you want to add NAT rules to **VMSS**' Load Balancer.

> But for now, adding or editing references between load balancers and scale set
>    virtual machines is currently **disabled** for load balancers that
>    contain an existing association with a scale set.

The command complains because you're trying to add a rule to something already configured with a pool.

If you want to add NAT rules to VMSS' Load Balancer, we should **redeploy** it with new configure. VMSS are configured slightly different than individual VM's. VMSS use pools for NAT rules rather than individual rules, more information about VMSS' Load Balancer, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/vmss-powershell-creating#configure-load-balancer).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Does your load balancer setup with VMSS?

Comment: Many thanks Jason. What exactly do we redeploy? Can you provide further details on this? Most importantly I'm worried about losing the VM instances that were generated for the VMSS. It would be great if they can at least keep their MAC addresses somehow, as I have software licenses running on those VM's and those licences are based on the MAC address assigned to the individual VM's.